# JSTL iterate list

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I have this class:

```
public class Orders{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    //getters/setters

}
```

In controller I pass a `List<Orders>` to `jsp`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders")
public ModelAndView orders(){

    List<Orders> orders = ...//get list from db

    //print list in console
    orders.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getId() + " - " + e.getName()));
    //print -> 1 - name1 ; 2 - name2

    return new ModelAndView("orders", "orders", orders);

}
```

In `jsp` use it like this:

```
${orders.size()}
<c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order">
    <c:out value="${order.getId()}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

In browser at inspect(html code) looks like this:

```
"2"
<c:foreach items="[com.web.entity.Orders@21e16dd6, 
                   com.web.entity.Orders@52a33913]" var="order">
    <c:out value=""></c:out>
</c:foreach>
```

I tested in controller by printing list in console and everything is right.

Why in jsp is not printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please provide more details (controller code, html page tags ...).
Still I've some point to share with you :

- Use always a toString method in your Entity/POJO.
- Use order.id instead of order.getId()
- Make sure you have JSTL core tag in the top of your HTML page :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

- Try to have a simple c:out tag:

```
<c:out value="${order.id}"/>
```

Comment: I added controller code to my question. I tried with `order.id` and same result. In HTML I don't have `taglib` and if I add it I get this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.LandingPage_jsp`. I used also simple `c:out `and same.

Comment: I solved that error by adding dependency: `taglibs-standard-impl`. So the main problem was at `taglib` in top of html.